# Is there an API to limit the line of logs in stackdriver?

Tags: stackdriver

I need to get recent 100 lines from a stack driver log. Is there any API which can be used to implement this scenario in stackdriver? currently I'm using Google cloud Java client to implement the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CLI gcloud command and "limit" for this:

gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND logName=projects/my-gcp-project-id/logs/syslog AND textPayload:SyncAddress" --limit 10 --format json

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#reading_log_entries